How can a Kenyan Deputy President challenge his impeachment after it passed the Senate?
The BBC:

Kenyan senators have voted to remove Deputy President Rigathi Gachagua from office despite his failure to testify at his impeachment trial after his lawyer said he had been taken to hospital. [...]
Last week, an overwhelming majority of MPs in the National Assembly - the lower house of parliament - voted to impeach him, setting the stage for his two-day trial in the Senate.
On Thursday evening, the required two-thirds of the 67 senators voted to oust him on charges that included corruption, inciting ethnic divisions and undermining the government.
The senators voted by a large majority to convict him on the first count - enough for him to to be removed from office.
Before the vote, Gachagua had said he would challenge the decision if it passed.

Does a Deputy President have any legal recourse left after  that conviction in the Senate?


Does a Deputy President have any legal recourse left after that
conviction in the Senate?

Short Answer
Yes.
The Senate conviction is subject to judicial review in the High Court of Kenya, which is in turn subject to the ordinary appeal process in Kenya's appellate courts from the High Court ruling.
The most solid issue in this appeal will be whether the Deputy President was denied his right under the Kenyan Constitution to have an opportunity to be heard at his Senate impeachment trial when he was not able to attend due to a medical emergency and the Senate moved forward with the trial anyway.
Long Answer
Removal of the Deputy President is governed by Article 150 of the Constitution of Kenya, which in turn incorporates by reference the provisions of Articles 144 (incapacity) and 145 (impeachment) of the Constitution of Kenya related to removing the President from office. Article 145 states:

Removal of President by impeachment.

(1) A member of the National Assembly, supported by at least a third of all the members, may move a motion for the impeachment of the
President—Constitution of Kenya, 2010

(a) on the ground of a gross violation of a provision of this
Constitution or of any other law;
(b) where there are serious reasons for believing that the President
has committed a crime under national or international law; or (c) for
gross misconduct.
(2) If a motion under clause
(1) is supported by at least two-thirds of all the members of the
National Assembly—
(a) the Speaker shall inform the Speaker of the Senate of that
resolution within two days; and
(b) the President shall continue to perform the functions of the
office pending the outcome of the proceedings required by this
Article.
(3) Within seven days after receiving notice of a resolution from the
Speaker of the National Assembly—
(a) the Speaker of the Senate shall convene a meeting of the Senate to
hear charges against the President; and
(b) the Senate, by resolution, may appoint a special committee
comprising eleven of its members to investigate the matter.
(4) A special committee appointed under clause (3) (b) shall—
(a) investigate the matter; and
(b) report to the Senate within ten days whether it finds the
particulars of the allegations against the President to have been
substantiated.
(5) The President shall have the right to appear and be represented
before the special committee during its investigations.
(6) If the special committee reports that the particulars of any
allegation against the President—
(a) have not been substantiated, further proceedings shall not be
taken under this Article in respect of that allegation; or
(b) have been substantiated, the Senate shall, after according the
President an opportunity to be heard, vote on the impeachment charges.
(7) If at least two-thirds of all the members of the Senate vote to
Constitution of Kenya, uphold any impeachment charge, the President
shall cease to hold office.

The Kenyan Constitution was adopted in 2010, and this is the first time this provision has been used (as far as I know).
The model adopted by the Kenyan Constitution rather closely parallels that of the U.S. Constitution's impeachment provisions found at Sections 2 and 3 of Article I of the U.S. Constitution (which also provides that "When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside"), and Section 4 of Article II of the U.S. Constitution (setting forth the grounds for impeachment of the President, Vice President and "all civil officers of the United States"). And, in U.S. law, impeachment is a "political question" which is largely beyond judicial review, largely as a consequence of Section 5 of Article I of the U.S. Constitution which states in the pertinent parts that:

Each House shall be the Judge of the Elections, Returns and
Qualifications of its own Members,and a Majority of each shall
constitute a Quorum to do Business; but a smaller Number may adjourn
from day to day, and may be authorized to compel the Attendance of
absent Members, in such Manner, and under such Penalties as each House
may provide.
Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings, punish its
Members for disorderly Behaviour, and, with the Concurrence of two
thirds, expel a Member.

and Section 2 of Article III of the U.S. Constitution which expressly excludes impeachments from the right to a jury trial.
Article 145(6)(b) afford an impeached President a right to be heard at his impeachment trial, which Article 150 incorporates by reference with respect to the impeachment of the Deputy President. (Something absent from the U.S. Constitution which leaves this question to the Senate except in cases of Presidential impeachments where it is left to the Chief Justice of the United States presiding over the Senate trial.)
So, the issues presented are: (1) whether an opportunity to be heard that was given to the Deputy President that wasn't utilized due to a medical emergency of the Deputy President violated his right to be heard under Articles 145(6)(b) and 150, and (2) whether the decision of the Kenyan Senate to move forward with the proceeding despite his failure to appear is subject to judicial review.
The possibility that the High Court of Kenya might have more authority over Parliament than the U.S. Supreme Court has over the impeachment process is suggested, for example, by Article 105 of the Constitution of Kenya, which gives the High Court rather than Parliament the authority to resolve disputes over whether a purported member of the National Assembly or Senate has been duly elected. In contrast, in the U.S., Congress is the final judge of its own elections as set forth in Section 5 of Article I of the U.S. Constitution.
Article 124(1) of the Constitution of Kenya states:

Each House of Parliament may establish committees, and shall make
Standing Orders for the orderly conduct of its proceedings, including
the proceedings of its committees.

So Parliament can make its own rules. But this does not make Parliament the final judge of its proceedings as the U.S. Constitution does. Instead, Article 165(3)(c) provides that:

(3) Subject to clause (5), the High Court shall have— . . .
(c) jurisdiction to hear an appeal from a decision of a tribunal
appointed under this Constitution to consider the removal of a person
from office, other than a tribunal appointed under Article 144;
. . .
(5) The High Court shall not have jurisdiction in respect of matters—
(a) reserved for the exclusive jurisdiction of the Supreme Court under
this Constitution [Ed. Presidential election disputes]; or (b) falling within the jurisdiction of the
courts contemplated in Article 162(2) [Ed. employment and environmental tribunals].

Thus, the High Court, which is the highest trial court in Kenya does have jurisdiction to consider the Deputy President's appeal of the Kenyan Senate's conviction of him in a impeachment trial, and its ruling is subject to further appeal to the Kenyan Court of Appeals and from there to the Kenyan Supreme Court, in contrast to the process under the U.S. Constitution.
So, the issue is expressly made justiciable under the Kenyan Constitution.
As a result, the question of whether an opportunity to be heard that was given to the Deputy President that wasn't utilized due to a medical emergency of the Deputy President violated his right to be heard under Articles 145(6)(b) and 150 can be presented to the High Court, and appealed to the Court of Appeals and then to the Supreme Court of Kenya if the Deputy President is not satisfied with the lower court results.
Honestly, looking at the issue as a neutral outsider, this question is a close one, isn't frivolous, and could go either way, particularly in light of the fact that this will be a question for first impression for the Kenyan courts.
Parliament could argue that the Senate is not a tribunal within the meaning of Article 165(3)(c), but given the larger context of the Kenyan Constitution, this is probably not a strong argument, particularly because Article 144 removal proceedings are expressly excluded from High Court jurisdiction, while Article 145 removal proceedings are not.
Presumably, if the Deputy President were to prevail in the High Court, the remedy it would order would be a new Senate trial at which the Deputy President is afforded an opportunity to be heard (or Parliament could abandon the impeachment and seek the remove the Deputy President for incapacity depending upon the nature of the medical event that led to his hospitalization). In all likelihood, the Senate would rule that same way at a retrial, so it might accept such a ruling rather than appealing it. The High Court would also presumably vacate the Senate Conviction if it ruled in this manner, affording the Deputy President a few more days in office (and the pay the comes with it).
